# How to select the following specific XML nodes using XPath?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have an XML doc like the following:

```
<Objects>
  <object distName="a/b">  </object>
  <object distName="a/b/c1">  </object>
  <object distName="a/b/c4/d/e">  </object>
  <object distName="a/b/c2">  </object>
  <object distName="a/b/c6/d">  </object>
</Objects>
```

And I need to select all nodes which has a path that ends with **"c" + number**. Like: "*a/b/c1*" and "*a/b/c2*" but not like "*a/b/c6/d*", nor "*a/b/c4/d/e*".

If I try the following:

```
      `cNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object[contains(@path, `a/b/c`)]")`
```

Then this will include "a/b/c6/d" and "a/b/c4/d/e" which is not what I require.

So is there a way to do the job ***in one or maybe two lines of code***. I mean I can do it with like a loop and stuff like that, which I don't want to. That's because the real XML doc is thousands of nodes.

PS: Python 2.7, lxml

Comment: No, path is just an attribute. It has nothing to do with the content.

Comment: @JeffMercado I changed the name from `path` to `distName`. Because I'm just giving an example. it's not exactly like the XML doc I have.

Comment: @JeffMercado Sorry, my mistake. I'll edit.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuantely it's not very simple to express a condition that matches patterns using XPath 1.0.  But if you can make certain assumptions about what you're looking for, you can craft such a query.

```
//object[starts-with(@distName, 'a/b/c') and substring-after(@distName, 'a/b/c') >= 0]
```

Breaking it up, we're first checking if the `distName` attribute starts with `a/b/c`.  Then if everything after that string is some number.  Depending on your needs, this might just be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this can't be done using pure XPath 1.0 which is XPath version that `lxml` supports.

As an alternative, you can try to split the attribute by `/`, get the last split result, and check if it starts with `c`, all in one line using list comprehension, for example :

```
>>> raw = '''<Objects>
...   <object distName="a/b">  </object>
...   <object distName="a/b/c1">  </object>
...   <object distName="a/b/c4/d/e">  </object>
...   <object distName="a/b/c2">  </object>
...   <object distName="a/b/c6/d">  </object>
... </Objects>'''
... 
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xmlDoc = etree.fromstring(raw)
>>> cNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object[contains(@path, 'a/b/c')]")
>>> result = [etree.tostring(n) for n in cNodes if n.attrib["distName"].split('/')[-1].startswith("c")]
>>> print result
['<object distName="a/b/c1">  </object>\n  ', '<object distName="a/b/c2">  </object>\n  ']
```

Comment: The thing is these cNodes are just parents of other nodes in the real XML file. And I care about selecting the nodes themselves. But looks like there is no other way but to go through a loop. Anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: No, looks like there is a solution. The accepted answer is just what I needed.